# binding events with wxpython

Tags: python, wxpython

I have the wxPyhon following code

```
self.button1 = wx.Button(self, id=-1, label='Button1',pos=(8, 8), size=(175, 28)) 
self.button2 = wx.Button(self, id=-1, label='Button2',pos=(16, 8), size=(175, 28))  
self.button1.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onButton)
self.button1.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onButton)
```

and I need to process the buttons in the below function according to the luanched event 
could someone provide an idea i.e

```
def button1Click(self,event):
    if(event of button1 ) : 
        #proccess code    
    if(event of button2 ):
        #proccess code
```

how can i know which button luanch the event

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to use the label (or ID...but that's usually more troublesome) to key off of, such as:

```
 def onButton(self, event):
    label = event.GetEventObject().GetLabel()
    if label == "foo":
         ...
    elif label == "bar":
         ....
```

Often times, I wish that it has a call back mechanism.  So another option is to use lambda during the bind.  See this [tutorial](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/07/19/the-python-lambda/)

Comment: Nice answer. It helped me, but I found out that it is even better is to use the method .GetName(), since the label can be a long string. Name can be easily set when creating the button.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a function for each of them if there's different processing code.

```
self.button1 = wx.Button(self, id=-1, label='Button1',pos=(8, 8), size=(175, 28))

self.button2 = wx.Button(self, id=-1, label='Button2',pos=(16, 8), size=(175, 28))

self.button1.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onButton1)

self.button1.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onButton2)

def onButton1(self,event):
    # process code

def onButton2(self,event):
    # process code
```

Comment: Also see http://wiki.wxpython.org/self.Bind%20vs.%20self.button.Bind or http://wiki.wxpython.org/Passing%20Arguments%20to%20Callbacks

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I like to get the button object itself:

```
button = event.GetEventObject()
```

Then I can use any of the button's methods, like GetName, GetId, or GetLabel. Setting the name is probably the easiest since sometimes I'll have two buttons with the same label.

```
myButton = wx.Button(self, label="blah blah", name="blah blah one")
```

Now you can be pretty sneaky. Somewhere in your program, you can have a dict that maps the button names with the methods they should run:

```
self.myDict = {"btnOne":methodOne, "btnTwo":methodTwo}
```

Then in your event handler, you can have something like

```
myButton = event.GetEventObject()
buttonName = myButton.GetName()
if buttonName in self.myDict:
    self.myDict[buttonName]()
```

See also http://wiki.wxpython.org/Passing%20Arguments%20to%20Callbacks or http://wiki.wxpython.org/self.Bind%20vs.%20self.button.Bind

Answer (score 0):

You could the buttons label to identify it like so

```
def onButton(self,event):
    buttonLabel =  event.GetEventObject().GetLabel()
    if buttonLabel == "Button1":
        doSomething()
    elif buttonLabel == "Button2":
        doSomethingElse()
```